# FormFlow : Cancel form after some times

Tags: c#, botframework, formflow

I would like to stop my formflow when the user doesn't answer after a certain amount of time.

```
public IForm<PatientForm> BuildForm()
        {
            if (dateFirstAnswer.AddSeconds(30) < DateTime.Now)
                return null;
            else
            {
                return new FormBuilder<PatientForm>()
                        .Message(ResourceStringExtentionsPatientForm.IntroForm.Spintax())
                        .OnCompletion(async (context, profileForm) =>
                        {
                            string message = ResourceStringExtentionsPatientForm.OutroForm.Spintax();
                            await context.PostAsync(message);
                        })
                        .Build();
            }
        }
```

I tried to return null but then I can't manage anything after leaving the formflow.

Return `new FormBuilder<PatientForm>().Build()` only skip 1 question, the formflow keep going.

Is there a way I can call the FormCommand.Quit like a user can do ?

Second question, I saw some example where BuildForm() is static, are there any reason to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
IForm<PatientForm> newForm;

public void BuildForm()
        {
            if (dateFirstAnswer.AddSeconds(30) > DateTime.Now)
            {
                newForm = new FormBuilder<PatientForm>()
                        .Message(ResourceStringExtentionsPatientForm.IntroForm.Spintax())
                        .OnCompletion(async (context, profileForm) =>
                        {
                            string message = ResourceStringExtentionsPatientForm.OutroForm.Spintax();
                            await context.PostAsync(message);
                        })
                        .Build();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I can't create an instance of `IForm` it's an interface.
And my main problem is that I need to quit the formflow and return something that I can use.

Comment: So return a blank IForm if you must have it.

Comment: I can't, it's an interface.

Comment: You can, what are you saying, just give blank values